How can I get markers and measures from a midi?
I´m getting the markers from a MIDI with this code:
from music21 import converter
import mido

# Ruta al archivo MIDI
archivo_midi = 'Song.mid'
# Abrir el archivo MIDI
mid = mido.MidiFile(archivo_midi)

# Cargar el archivo MIDI
midi = converter.parse(archivo_midi)

# Obtener las "flags" de las secciones
for msg in mid:
    if msg.type == 'marker':
        etiqueta = msg.text
        print(f"Etiqueta: {etiqueta}")

I would want to get measures when occur the markers found too. Does some one know how can I do it??? Before hand Thanks by your interesting comments.

There are no "measures" in MIDI itself, only tempo and time signature events, with all note data using time-since-last event deltas. You're going to have to run through the MIDI events and manually calculate which measure an event occurs using standard "if the time signature is 4:4 and we're running 120 BPM and this event happens 25 seconds in, that means it's 50 beats into the score, which means it's in measure floor(50/4)", and then you'll have to make sure to compensate for time signature and tempo changes if and when they occur.
